# Oracle APEX - Is it possible to submit a value to session state without refreshing the entire page?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I've got a page that has a bunch of Select List items.
Each Select List item underneath the next executes an SQL query to retrieve the previous item's value from the session state, and displays a new list based on the result.

I can get everything to work by allowing each Select List item to 'Submit to Page', which refreshes the entire page. Seeing as there are 5+ Select List items, it's not very user-friendly to have the user wait on each refresh.

Is there a way to either get the value from a Select List into the session state without refreshing the page, or for an SQL Query to take the value from the previous Select List item and use it in it's query to display a new list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Cascading LOVs. Here is a short example on how to use them.

Let's say you want to have 2 select lists one with departments and one with the employees that work in the selected department. So we need a table `DEPARTMENTS(department_id, deparment_name)` with all your departments and a table `EMP(emp_id, emp_name, department_id)` with all the employees and in what department they work in.

Create your first select list named `P1_DEPARTMENTS` with the List of Values SQL Query like this `select department_name, department_id from departments`

Now create the second select list named `P1_EMPLOYEES` using the List of Values SQL Query

`select emp_name, emp_id from EMP where department_id=:P1_DEPARTMENTS`

Now in the **Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)** attribute of `P1_EMPLOYEES` select list you have to select the item that you want to pass as a parent in our case the `P1_DEPARTMENTS`.

Now when you select a value in the `P1_DEPARTMENTS` select list the `P1_EMPLOYEES` select list will refresh and you will get just the employees that work in the selected department.